# Common Pattern to Initialize A Singleton On A Background Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, design-patterns, singleton

I currently have a singleton, which can take up to 10 seconds to initialize. However, I don't want my users to penalized (waiting) for this initialize, so I'd rather bootstrap this component on a background thread during application startup. Here's what I have:

Singleton:

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private static MySingleton _instance;
    private static readonly object _locker = new object();

    private MySingleton() 
    {
        Init();
    }
    public static MySingleton Instance 
    { 
        if(_instance == null) _instance = new MySingleton();
        return _instance;
    }
    public void Init()
    {
        lock(_locker)
        {
            if(_instance != null) return;

            // long running code here...
        }
    }
}
```

Application Startup:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MySingleton.Instance.Init());
```

This code does work, guards against double init, guards against the edge case of the user needing it before it's done initializing and also guards against someone forgetting to call Init().

However, it feels a little clunky for two reasons:
a) I'm going to go into the Init method twice on startup.
b) I'd like to do threading inside the singleton, but something has to initiate the initialization.

Is there a cleaner/nicer/better way to handle this?

Thanks in advance for everyone's help.

**EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, Init was mistakenly scoped as private. It should be public and has been corrected.

Comment: You should be using `Lazy<>` to initialize your singleton [as preached by Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) to offload the initialization until the singleton is actually used.

Comment: Jon states in that article "My personal preference is for solution 4: " which is not the Lazy<T> solution. Please read article for his reasoning and more info.

Comment: @MitchWheat - Heh, I guess (in the 10+ times I've read it) I never read the article past the examples. That'll teach me to hold my tongue (probably not though)

Comment: How are you calling Init() on startup when it's a private method?

Comment: @M.Babcock: The last section was only (relatively) recently added.

Comment: @MitchWheat - That would explain why I've never seen it. The implementation here still differs though so I don't feel so bad.

Comment: So why are you calling `Init()` and not just `MySingleton.Instance`?  Additionally you'll need to have a lock around the `if(_instance==null) check or else every single call to `Instance` while it's being initialized will cause a new constructor to be called.

Comment: Here's a crazy idea: don't use singletons at all.

Comment: @Servy: saying Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MySingleton.Instance); is akward and is not intent revealing.

Comment: @pdalbe01 That's what comments are there for; when the correct code is hard to understand and code that looks correct either won't work, or won't work as well.

Answer (score 12):

Use the static constructor to trigger it and a `ManualResetEvent` for the syncing. It gives you a solution where everything is done within the actual class. It's therefore not dependent of that someone should call your init method.

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private static MySingleton _instance;
    private static ManualResetEvent _initEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    static MySingleton() 
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Init());
    }

    public static MySingleton Instance 
    {
        _initEvent.Wait();
        return _instance;
    }
    private static void Init()
    {
        _instance = new MySingleton();
        // long running code here...


        _initEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

The event will stay signaled once triggered which means that the Instance property will return ASAP when the Init method is done.

Comment: Terrific solution! Thanks! Couple of questions though: a) any reason to QueueUserWorkItem and not Task.Factory.StartNew()? b) Any reaosn to use ManualResetEvent and not an AutoResetEvent?

Comment: a) No, personal preference. b) Yes. `AutoResetEvent` will reset the signal and block all callers when the first `Wait` have completed

Comment: Slight issue: static constructors are only invoked the first time a class member is used. So this wouldn't run Init() during app startup.

Comment: @pdalbe01 is right. The solution as posed will run (at latest) on first use. You can add a dummy function to trigger instantiation on command. Something like 

public static bool CreateInstanceInBackground() { return _instance == null; } 

which you can call in your main constructor if you want to force startup.

Answer (score 0):

You should define and call singleton class as below...

```
  var instance = MySingleton.Instance;
  while (true)
  {
     /// check for whether singleton initialization complete or not
     if (MySingleton.Initialized)
     {
       break;
     }
  }



  public class MySingleton
        {
            private static MySingleton _instance;
            private static readonly object _locker = new object();
            public static bool Initialized { get; set; }

            private MySingleton()
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(call => Init());
            }

            public static MySingleton Instance
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                        _instance = new MySingleton();

                    return _instance;
                }
            }

            private void Init()
            {
                lock (_locker)
                {
                    if (Initialized)
                        return;
                    // long running code here...         
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                    {

                    }
                    Initialized = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd mybe go with a `Task<T>`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MySingleton.Init();

        Thread.Sleep(7000);

        Console.WriteLine("Getting instance...");
        var mySingleton = MySingleton.Instance;
        Console.WriteLine("Got instance.");
    }

    public class MySingleton
    {
        private static Lazy<MySingleton> instance;

        public static MySingleton Instance
        {
            get { return instance.Value; }
        }

        public static void Init()
        {
            var initTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Doint init stuff {0}...", i);
                }

                return new MySingleton();
            });

            instance = new Lazy<MySingleton>(() => initTask.Result);
        }

        private MySingleton() { }
    }
}
```